# When using the aws cli command, aws acm list-certificates, is there a way to get it to return certificates that do not have a domain name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-cli, aws-acm

As part of my infrastructure I need to upload a certificate to acm from my own certificate authority. Uploading it using the `aws acm import-certificate` command works fine the main difference between this cert and the amazon issued ones that are already on there being that it doesn't have a value for the domain name field.

The problem comes when I want to list the certificates in the acm to check if the certificate I uploaded is present or not at a later time. When I run `aws acm list-certificates` the cert I uploaded is not present in the result.

From the [docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/acm/list-certificates.html#options):

> Default filtering returns only RSA_1024 and RSA_2048 certificates that have at least one domain.

My cert is RSA_2048. Therefore, I think that when I use `aws acm list-certificates` that the certificate I uploaded is being filtered out of the result as it does not have a domain name.

Having read through the linked documentation page a couple times now I can't see a way to configure the filtering not to filter on the domain name field.

Is it possible to get `list-certificates` to return a certificate where the certificate doesn't have a domain name?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. The workaround is to have at least something in the filter which replaces the default filter completely.

Example:`aws acm list-certificates --includes keyUsage=DIGITAL_SIGNATURE`

Same workaround works using the .Net client:

```
var request = new Amazon.CertificateManager.Model.ListCertificatesRequest();
request.Includes = new Amazon.CertificateManager.Model.Filters();
```